# How to conduct EM algorithm when there are some outliers in GMM Models?

Tags: optimization, outliers, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I'm just confused about the problem of adding an outlier component directly to the primary form of GMM models:

Suppose that the observed data contains several outliers. The mixture model could be:

$$
p(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{k=1}^{K} w_{k} p\left(\boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{\mu}_{k}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{k}\right)+w_{K+1}, \quad \boldsymbol{w}=\left[w_{1}, \ldots, w_{K+1}\right] \in \Delta^{K}
$$

and $w_{K+1}$ is probability that the sample is an outlier.

So how to modify this $\mathrm{EM}$ algorithm to learn the model?

I just think about replace $w_{k+1}$ with $1-\sum_{k=1}^K w_k$, but find it difficult to distinguish whether optimizing the objective of $\sum_{k=1}^{K} w_{k} p\left(\boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{\mu}_{k}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{k}\right)$ is essentially different with the objective of $\sum_{k=1}^{K} w_{k} p\left(\boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{\mu}_{k}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{k}\right),s.t. \sum_{k=1}^K w_k=1$.?? How to convert the extra component of $w_{k+1}$ ..?

Comment: Assuming that your data can come from the full Euclidean space, the "model" you wrote down there is not a valid probability model, as integrating it over the whole space gives infinity, not 1. You may be interested in this: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v18/16-382.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just missed a constraint that $\sum_{k=1}^{K+1} w_k=1$  and I'll read it carefully and I really appreciate your helpful reply!!  ☺️

Comment: The constraint doesn't solve the problem. Integrating a constant $w_{K+1}$ over the whole Euclidean space gives infinity. In the linked paper in fact we do something like this, but there are issues, and these are also discussed there.

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah,  I just caught a little about your ideas 

Comment: Actually I also saw a similar problem in stack-overflow and one reply said "your model is messy because the two components are not in the same space",  it might be indicate the similar ideas..

Comment: An alternative approach by the way is implemented in the mclust package in R, which is to use a uniform density over the convex hull of the data as distribution for the outliers. Look at their reference manual at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/ You may search the term "noise" to find it; references also given there.

Comment: Our own package is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/otrimle/

Comment: Wow thanks for your reply !! it really helps a lot !!! Thank u  ☺️